# How can I see a list of commands for each MiKTeX package?

Tags: documentation

For example, take the 'textcomp' package. I can only find commands like \textdegree, etc. from here and there. Is there a way to see all the available commands for this as well as other packages?

(Note: I have found http://cialdea.altervista.org/manuali/symbols-a4.pdf, which includes quite a couple of lists for this package but it's not exhaustive. Moreover, it includes only a few packages.)

Comment: the documentation for `textcomp`  can be accessed via `texdoc textcomp` (or it is on ctan) and has the list of encoding specific commands defined by that package in section 4.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the OP would like a master index, which correlates each package with the commands it provides, and likewise identifies the package if you already know the command. This has been asked before, I believe, and the answer is a definite no. Part of the problem is that many packages re-define commands, and part of the problem is that nobody has made such a list, because packages change so frequently. Not specific to MikTeX.

Comment: @RobtAll: Perhaps you're right, but on the other hand the OP seems to look for symbol commands, like `\textdegree` etc and not for other macros like `\section` or \tableofcontents etc.

Comment: @RobtAll yes but it helps if you look in the package documentation for package commands rather than other places that document other things, my comment was just a pointer in the right direction

Comment: You would have to update this catalog constantly.  When I want to find out which package provides a particular command is to do a 'Search in Files' over all packages (at least, all the ones I have loaded admin).

Comment: David, I run 'texdoc textcomp' and it issues "Documentation for textcomp could not be found".

Comment: Christian, I think I already mentioned http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, didn't I? :)

Anyway, I got it. MiKTeX people have created 462 programs (.exe files) (in my package) and I don;t know how many packages, but they have not thought of creating one more that shows the contets of each package!  Quite interesting, isn't it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I'm sorry. Reviewing the comments, I downloaded the PDF of your link and saw that it is completely different and, inded, much more "comprehensive" than the one I had, which was dated 2001 and had 56 pages, whereas yours is dated 2017 and has 338 pages!!! Thanks a lot for the ref!